# Updating values and returning updated values in Entity framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity

i have a table which i use to implement a sequence in Sql Server 2008. The sequence table has just 1 column which is an integer.

I want to know if i can do something like this

```
update dbo.MySequence set val=val+1 output inserted.val
```

and return value without using stored procedures in Entity Framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to avoid stored procedures? Using stored procedures is part of using EF. You don't have to create stored procedure but you still have to call direct SQL (for example with `context.ExecuteStoreQuery`). For example on MS SQL you can use:

```
DECLARE @val INT
UPDATE dbo.MySequence SET @val = val = val + 1
SELECT @val
```

But it is better to have sequences named (with additional column).

Comment: Thanks @ladislav, but due to some design constraints, stored procedures are not an option and i want to make a single hit to the DB to get the updated value.

Comment: Pure EF is not able to do that in single roundtrip without help of database or direct SQL. What database are you using? This looks like typical Identity column in MSSQL and Oracle's sequences should be hopefully covered directly.